# Select random VPN target server when starting openVPN with systemd

Tags: linux, openvpn, systemd

I have written a systemd file to start my VPN Service using a particular configuration file. What I would like to be able to do is have this file replaced with a randomly selected configuration file each time the service starts.

So far i have tried using

```
ExecStartPre=cp -f `ls /etc/openvpn/ovpn_udp/au* | shuf -n 1` /etc/openvpn/%i.conf
```

to copy the randomly picked file to the specified configuration file. Some alternativly I have tried are

- used rsync -c instead of cp
- double quotes around the whole ExecStartPre command
- escaping the `

Finally I have also tried the following ExecStart to

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --config `ls /etc/openvpn/ovpn_udp/au* | shuf -n 1`
```

All with no effect.

Currently the systemd file is as follows

```
[Unit]
Description=OpenVPN Robust And Highly Flexible Tunneling Application On %I
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=notify
PrivateTmp=true
ExecStartPre=cp -f `ls /etc/openvpn/ovpn_udp/au* | shuf -n 1` /etc/openvpn/%i.conf
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/%i.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I am expecting the configuration file to be changed before each start of the service but so far I don't see any errors or the configuration file being replaced.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ExecStart= command **is not run by a shell** and does not provide the usual shell language features. About the only things it has are quoting and $variable substitution – but it **does not have** pipes or `backticks` or $(command substitution).

In order to use these features, a) explicitly run a shell like /bin/sh:

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "cp `foo | bar` baz"
```

or b) move your commands into a shell script and run *that* from ExecStart=.

Note that OpenVPN itself already supports declaring multiple servers *within the same configuration*, using `<connection>` blocks and `--remote-random`, as shown in its manual page:

```
client
remote-random
<connection>
remote foo.example.com 1194 udp
</connection>
<connection>
remote bar.example.com 1194 udp
</connection>
```

Comment: See **COMMAND LINES** in `systemd.service(5)`: "*Specifically, redirection using "<", "<<", ">", and ">>", pipes using "|", running programs in the background using "&", and other elements of shell syntax are not supported.*"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @grawity that clears things up a lot. Utilising your answer I have now successfully modified my systemd service file to the below that does exactly what i need.

```
[Unit]
Description=OpenVPN Robust And Highly Flexible Tunneling Application On %I
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=notify
PrivateTmp=true
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c "ls /etc/openvpn/ovpn_udp/au* | shuf -n 1 | xargs -r -n1 -I'{}' cp -f '{}' /etc/openvpn/%i.conf"
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/%i.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```